# Exclude version with qualifier from dependencies in POM file

Tags: maven-3, autotest

we use maven to run and build our autotests. 
Also we have different projects with dependencies on other autotests projects.

For example we have Project1 with release version  (1.2.2). 
Project2 has dependency on Project1 like: [1.2.0,1.3.0)

When somebody make some changes to Project1 we deploy 1.2.3-dev to test it on our environment. But in this case, Project2 will use 1.2.3-dev as latest.
We need to make Project2 not to use dependency with "dev" qualifier ever. So it should ignore all builds with "dev" qualifier.

Is there any way to do it?

Using SNAPSHOT is not an option for us right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`versions:resolve-ranges`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/resolve-ranges-mojo.html) to forcefully resolve versions on your terms. Simply run this as a separate build step immediately before your main build step. This goal can be configured to exclude certain artifacts (of certain versions/classifiers) using `-Dexcludes=groupId:artifactId:type:classifier:version`.

The best practice, however, is to avoid using version ranges in the first place, in order to get fully reproducible builds. Because otherwise builds can break simply by, e.g., a new buggy release of an external dependency.